# How to understand the class name add <> symbol?

Tags: c#, il

How to understand this code in C#?

```
using System;
internal class <Module>
{
}
```

The class name can't contain the symbol `<>` but it is allowed to have it in code? How would you achieve this? And how can I understand this difference?

Take a look at this code:

```
internal class <Module>{D8BAC701-C957-4CBE-8F97-37BB3A7DAFFE}
{
    static <Module>{D8BAC701-C957-4CBE-8F97-37BB3A7DAFFE}()
    {
        if (!(eqXmHMg8VVPy3nYeAo.eHiMp4DL8(Convert.ToBase64String(Type.GetTypeFromHandle(epOl6XynGueNUNwY5Y.e53w34m968awCm9P85taUZe(33554477)).Assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken()), "eObc8gibn") != "34NavQ/3DsKjaKpYVSNSMjtuaXO9zUZlQl7AY+p3wrM="))
        {
            return;
        }
        while (true)
        {
            eqXmHMg8VVPy3nYeAo.ce4DmfsmSrOT856tDgfrkMb();
        }
    }
}
```

This class doesn't even have a namespace.

I decompiled this DLL with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). But how can I use this code and de-obfuscate it?

Comment: I think you are missing the class name here and mentioning the generic type only. this should be some thing like this,internal class MyClass<GenericType>{}. 
For more details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know where this code is coming from, but it looks like decompiled code. You're not allowed to write such code but the compiler does. The compiler often uses "unspeakable names" to prevent name collisions with your code.

Comment: @Knickedi You're not allowed to write such code *in C#*. But you could write it if you were writing IL directly.

Comment: @svick You're absolutely right. I should've been more precise instead implying knowledge. (The question was _How to understand this code in C#?_ and this is invalid C# code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it could be [obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) code. That's code that is compiled into IL in a way that is still valid, but can't be easily understood by humans.

This works because the rules for valid identifiers are different in C# and IL. So, when you try to decompile the code, you're getting invalid C#, but the IL itself is valid.

Also, classes don't have to be in namespaces, even in C#.

Comment: Thank you,i will try to understand it.Have you any property /good suggestion ?