# C# disassembly default namespace module class

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is simple but I can't find an explanation.

When disassembling .net with ILSpy or ILDASM there is a class named `<module>` in the default namespace.

Why and how the compiler puts it there?
I have this:

```
using abc;
using System;

internal class <Module>
{
    static <Module>()
    {
        AssemblyLoader.Attach();
    }
}
internal interface ISomething
{
}
```

This is not the standart declaration. If I'm recreating C# project how would I add that?
Also the way I see it it is in a static constructor and will get executed before the entrypoint, so if I put `AssemblyLoader.Attach();` in my Main() or in a static constructor of `Program` (I'm using console app template) this should do the trick, right?

Comment: [C#  - Understand the class name add <> symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615662/how-to-understand-the-class-name-add-symbol)

Comment: [Module initializers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17379410/399414)

Comment: That is illegal syntax for C#, but not for IL. The compiler generates these kinds of implicit classes all the time for a multitude of reasons. The short answer is, no, you cannot recreate that.

Comment: Yes I understand why it is called that way, I wander how to make the compiler output the same thing though..

Comment: Well how to implement that call in my project - AssemblyLoader.Attach();

Answer (score 3):

You can't add code directly to `<Module>` from the VS or C# code. You can do it from the IL.

If you disassemble your code you can put a static `.cctor` which would end up being the `<Module>` constructor. It has to be outside any `.class`

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static void .cctor () cil managed 
{
    //put your code here
}
```

You can see [an example](https://github.com/pawlos/hackingil-examples/blob/master/module-inject/module_inject.il) in my repo on github.

Or use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)'s tool and particularly [ModuleInit](https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit).

Comment: I understand but I would like to do this in my C# code. I don't need to produce the same output, I just need the method to be called appropriately

Comment: @JODE - the closes thing to C# is to use Fody. There you can mark one of your C# method to be injected into the module. But it's still done the same way - just you don't need to know the details how it's done.